# allow my users to access my web application offline

Tags: java

Dont know if i am asking a right question but there's a requirement of this feature in or java based web application (used GWT[Google web toolkit])

Application is on cloud , Users access the application from their browser and perform some action and application has a linked database.(MySQL)

Now what need to be done is , If sometime a user is offline , they still need to access some part of the application (From Mobile/Tablets)
save some of their work while being offline.

and next time when user gets Online , they should be able to upload that saved work to our cloud database.

---

Please give me some hint how can i achieve this , i.e is it possible for my users to access my web application from their Mobile while being offline and also see the latest database data.(at the time when they were last online).

Comment: You can do something with cache or internal storages?

Comment: Some javascript libraries makes this. You build your database in clients LocalStorage. Javascript is synchronizing client storage with server database.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [HTML5 Storage Spec](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage.html#WhatIsStorage) of GWT.